# Find the number of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*},*)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Find the number of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*},*)$

This question appeared in my university exam but I couldn't solve it then. I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*}$ is the set of elements smaller than 7 and coprime to it. Hence this set is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. As the order of this group is 6 the subgroups can be of the order 2 or 3, by Lagrange Theorem. But I can't see how to find the exact number of subgroups.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In general, the number of subgroups depends on the group structure, not just the number of elements of the group. There aren't that many groups of order 6 up to isomorphism. Which group is $(\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*},*)$ isomorphic to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2$ and $3$ are primes, then you already know that these subgroups have to by cyclic. So in this particular case you can simply go through all elements one by one, and manually calculate cyclic subgroups:

$$\langle 1\rangle=\{1\}$$
$$\langle 2\rangle=\{2, 4, 1\}$$
$$\langle 3\rangle=\{3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1\}$$
$$\langle 4\rangle=\{4, 2, 1\}$$
$$\langle 5\rangle=\{5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1\}$$
$$\langle 6\rangle=\{6, 1\}$$

which I evaluated simply by starting at the generator, multiplying at each step by it and taking "$mod\ 7$" until I reach $1$. You can even turn that into a computer program.

Note that $\langle 3\rangle=\langle 5\rangle=\mathbb{Z}^*_7$ and so the entire group is cyclic. Which also follows from order analysis or general result on multiplicative group of a finite field.

By removing duplicates this gives us $4$ distinct subgroups in total.

---

Another approach, more general is to use the fact I referred to earlier: a multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic. Since $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a field, then $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_6$. And a cyclic group $C_n$ has this property that for any $m|n$ there is precisely one subgroup $H\subseteq C_n$ of order $m$. In particular the number of subgroups of $C_n$ is equal to the number of divisors of $n$. Which in case $n=6$ is $4$.

Comment: In the textbook I'm following it is mentioned that a subgroup should have the following properties: 
1. It should be a group itself with respect to the same operation

2. It should have the identity element

3. Inverse of every element in the subgroup should also be present in the subgroup

4. It should be closed under the given operation

Considering these properties, isn't {1,3,5} also a valid subgroup of the given group?

Comment: @lettuce no. The group operation we are dealing with here is **multiplication** modulo $7$. The neutral element is $1$. Also note that $3\cdot 3=2\ (mod\ 7)$, but $2$ is not an element of $\{1,3,5\}$.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now. Thanks!